# when need to set Block replication to 1

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, ambari

We get the following in Spark logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage DatanodeInfoWithStorage\
The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs

.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DFSOutputStream.java:1036)
```

My Ambari cluster includes only 3 workers machines and each worker have only one data disk.

I searched on Google and found solution can be about block replication. Block replication in HDFS is configured to 3 by default and I found the suggestion to set the "Block replication" to 1 instead of 3.

Question: does it make sense?

Furthermore, can the fact that my worker machine only has one data disk be part of the problem?

> *Block replication = The total number of files in the file system will be what's specified in the dfs.replication factor setting
>   dfs.replication=1, means will be only one copy of the file in the file
>   system.*

**The full log:**

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.31:50010,DS-8234bb39-0fd4-49be-98ba-32080bc24fa9,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.33:50010,DS-b4758979-52a2-4238-99f0-1b5ec45a7e25,DISK]], original=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.31:50010,DS-8234bb39-0fd4-49be-98ba-32080bc24fa9,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.33:50010,DS-b4758979-52a2-4238-99f0-1b5ec45a7e25,DISK]]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DFSOutputStream.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.addDatanode2ExistingPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DFSOutputStream.java:993)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:500)
---2018-01-30T15:15:15.015 INFO  [][][] [dal.locations.LocationsDataFramesHandler]
```

Comment: setting 1 as replication it may not be possible to recover if anything goes wrong. why would you want to do that ?

Comment: I think to set it because the error from the log as described in my question , if you think there are other solution for "Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try" I will hapy to know about it

Comment: I see some other link that talk about my problem - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/27153/getting-ioexception-failed-to-replace-a-bad-datano.html

Comment: and they suggest to set the following :               
dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy=ALWAYS
dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.best-effort=true   , but where to set this values , not see them in my ambari cluster

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The default block replication is 3. So, all files are created with replication factor of 3, unless you specify otherwise.

If any of the datanode is not reachable (network issues or if no space left of disk) , then replication will fail.

Check the datanode status using:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

In my case, I have 2 nodes on development, 1 is master and 1 is a datanode. So,I changed the replication factor to 1.

You can test this first from hdfs cli as below:

```
    echo "test file line1" > copy1
    echo "test file line2" >  copy2
    hdfs dfs -Ddfs.replication=1 -touchz /tmp/appendtest.txt
    hdfs dfs -appendToFile copy1 /tmp/appendtest.txt
    hdfs dfs -appendToFile copy2 /tmp/appendtest.txt
```

If in the `touchz` command, you don't specify the replication factor, you will get the same error when you try to append localfile `copy2`

The below configuration for the hdfsConfig object solved the problem for me:

```
  hdfsConfiguration.set("fs.defaultFS", configuration.getString("hdfs.uri"))
  hdfsConfiguration.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getName)
  hdfsConfiguration.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
  hdfsConfiguration.set("dfs.support.append", "true")
  hdfsConfiguration.set("dfs.replication", "1")
```